# If an overridden C++ function calls the parent function, which calls another virtual function, what is called?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm learning about polymorphism, and I am confused by this situation:
Let's say I have the following C++ classes:

```
class A{
    ...
    virtual void Foo(){
        Boo();
    }
    virtual void Boo(){...}
}

class B : public A{
    ...
    void Foo(){
        A::Foo();
    }  
    void Boo(){...}
}
```

I create an instance of B and call its Foo() function. When that function calls A::Foo(), will the Boo() method used be that of class A or B? Thanks!

Comment: Well try it out and see what happens!

Comment: I don't like these "try it yourself" comments. What you find out trying it out yourself is __what your compiler does under your test's artificial circumstances__. That might not be what you wanted to know. While I can see that _in this case_ it's hard to imagine a compiler getting this wrong, what if ODdol, unsure about how `virtual` works, set up the test so that the function is called from the class' constructor? One such mistake might throw a student back two weeks. __In the end, this site is for getting answers.__ If questions annoy you, why are you reading them?

Comment: @sbi: No, but it's a good starting point.  As in: I have this question, and here's what I see.  Is that normal?

Comment: @Bill:  The problem with that is that the test is neither necessary nor sufficient, assuming you're interested in any generality whatsoever.  People who know the language can answer without the test, and just running the test doesn't tell you whether the answer might be unspecified, implementation-defined, or even undefined.  Asking here is a good idea.

Comment: @David: I agree.  That's why asking here was the main part of my comment, just with the extra information. :)

Comment: @Bill: no. the "extra information" is the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you qualify a function call with the class, all method calls will be treated equal, that is dynamic dispatch if virtual, static dispatch if not virtual. When you fully qualify with the class name the method you are calling you are effectively disabling the dynamic dispatch mechanism and introducing a direct method call.

```
class A{
    virtual void Foo(){
        Boo();           // will call the final overrider
        A::Boo();        // will call A::Boo, regardless of the dynamic type
    }
    virtual void Boo();
};
class B : public A{
    void Foo(){
        //Foo();         // Would call the final overrider 
                         // (in this case B: infinite recursion)
        A::Foo();        // Will call A::Foo, even if the object is B
    }  
    void Boo();
};
```

The implicit `this` pointer is not an important part of the discussion here, as exactly the same happens when the call is made with an explicit object:

```
B b;
b.Foo();    // will call B::Foo -- note 1
b.A::Foo(); // will call A::Foo
```

Note 1: in this example, the compiler can elide the dynamic dispatch mechanism as it knows the concrete type of the instance (it sees the definition and it is not a reference/pointer) but you can imagine the same would happen if `b` was a reference, or equivalently if it was a pointer with `->` instead of `.`

Answer (score 2):

Since `Boo()` is virtual, the derived class' override is called.

`Boo();` is just a short-hand for `this->Boo();`, where you can see that a *virtual function is called through a pointer*. (`this` is of type `A* const` within `Foo()`.) And virtual functions called through a reference or a pointer will always call the override in the most-derived class (except when called from a constructor or destructor).

Answer (score 1):

Inside A,

```
virtual void Foo(){
        Boo();
    }
```

gets translated to `this->Boo()` ;since Boo is declared virtual in A, the derived class's method Boo gets called. Try not declaring Boo as virtual in A just for experimentation -- you'd see that A->Boo() is getting called.

Arpan